# IIS bindings and google analytics

Tags: iis, google-analytics

I have a question that relates to setting up google analytics on a website. I have one website setup on a Microsoft server using IIS. Let's call it www.example.com 
for this website I have added a couple of binds that relate to the different domains like www.example.eu and www.example.gov

With this is mind I only have one website to manage and to control and all the bindings exist just to have the possibility of using all the domains purchase without having any redirects when an user try to reach the website.

It's now time to start the analytics. But I'm getting a bit confused on how I'm going to setup this.
I'm I corerect and thinking that the only thing I need to add to my website is the following code?

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<script async src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

Or do I need to think of a cross domain setup like?

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
    <script>
    window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-Y', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
  ga('require', 'linker');
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['www.example.eu, 'www.example.gov'] );
<script async src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>
    <!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

Again www.example.eu and www.example.gov is not a website but just a bind to one www.example.com.

Hope you can help me to figure it out the best way to setup google analytics.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Analytics is a client-side technology, so it does not really "know" about your server settings and simply looks what is in the address bar of the browser.

If your users can browser the different domain names, ***and*** you expect them to change between domains during a session then you need the cross-domain setup with the linker.

If your users can access your website via different domains, but you do not expect them to change from on domain to the other during the visit then you do not need the cross-domain setup.

(For completeness sake, if you had redirects your would not need cross domain tracking either as long as the redirect is done via the server, or done client-side before the tracking code is executed).